# Nonlinear, second order system of ODEs not solved by Mathematica, solution however exists

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I am currently working on solving a system of two coupled nonlinear second order ODEs.
I have already shown by hand, that 2 real solutions, as polynomials of second order, exist but I want to use Mathematica (which I never have used before) to find more solutions, possibly one to a more restricted initial value problem.

We are expecting something which "looks like" a 4-th order polynomial (it isn't however) and the solutions to the system of ODEs shouldn't agree, given inital values.

I managed to get some numerical plots, which look exactly like the solution we want and I really want to make sure that the code I use trying to solve it symbolically is not flawed or that I can somehow tranform both ODEs into something Mathematica can solve symbolically. The following 2 ODEs are almost symmetric

```
eqns = {
0==sigma^2/2*y''[t]+(mu-K/2*x'[t]-K/2*y'[t])*y'[t]-delta*y[t]+(t-rho)^2+K/4*y'[t], 
0==sigma^2/2*x''[t]+(mu-K/2*x'[t]-K/2*y'[t])*x'[t]-delta*x[t]+(t-rho)^2+K/4*x'[t]
};
sol=Assuming[ delta>0&& K>0&& sigma>0,DSolve[eqns, {x,y}, {t,-2,2}
]]
```

The program however just spits back out

```
DSolve[ the input...]
```

which, accoding to my "research" means that Mathematica can't solve the system.
It somehow doesn't even output the two 2nd order polynomials I obtained by hand. I tried implementing the assumptions of our model using "Assuming[...]".

Is there nothing I can do to at least retrieve the 2nd order polynomials and proceed from there? Or can I somehow help Mathematica in any way?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably you made several assumptions (like `K!= 0`,`delta!=0`) to get your polynomial solution.

Comment: Oh I thought mathematica would make these on the way! I will look up how to implement those; thanks for the tip!

Comment: It's only a guess. I tried to find the polynomial solution "by hand" using Mathematica. In the quadratic polynomial solution I found terms `1/K`, `1/delta`

Comment: I have now implemented the assumptions using Assuming[sigma>0 && K>0 && delta>0,DSolve....] THis however changes nothing :(

Comment: Additional I observed that the polynomial solution isn't unique . Perhaps you know initial condition or somthing else to force a unique solution?

Comment: Yeah indeed there are 3 more solutions, but we expected the leading ($p$) coefficient to be positive. Indeed there are some more conditions which I could use to identify a "desired" solution, but for these I need at least one of the two functions :(. Do I have to guarantee uniqueness for mathematica to spit something out?

Comment: No usually not, but sometimes it helps...

Comment: You have three(!) equations `eqns`! `NDSolve` needs initial or boundary conditions too.

Comment: I just managed to get at least some plots :D

Comment: It is not uncommon for `DSolve` to fail to solve equations that people can solve.